# Compound normal distribution with mean from truncated normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to compute the distribution of a compound normal where the mean is drawn from a truncated normal.

To be specific, I want to find the unconditional distribution $p(\theta)$, when the conditional distribution $\theta|\tau \sim N(\tau,\sigma^2)$  is normal and $\tau$ is drawn from a truncated normal.  The distribution of $\tau$ is proportional to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ above the truncation point $t$.

I think that the resulting (unconditional) distribution for $\theta$ is normal (a picture from a simulation is below) and I want to work out its the parameters.

Wikipedia states that when $t=-\infty$ the resulting distribution is normal:

"Compounding a Gaussian distribution with mean distributed according to another Gaussian distribution yields a Gaussian distribution."
([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution))

But neither the page nor the references provided there contain a proof of this.  Does anyone have any other suggestions for references?  I'm pretty sure that if I saw the case with $t=-\infty$ then I could extend it to my case.  Thanks!

Picture below of simulation with 1000000 points. $\mu=0, \sigma=2, t=1$.  Blue line is a normal fitted with the sample mean and variance of the simulated $\theta$.

[image: Simulation results]

EDIT: I extended the problem to allow for non-identical variances and auto-regression in $\theta$.  So $\theta|\tau \sim N(\rho\tau,\epsilon^2)$ where $|\rho|<1$. But the untruncated distribution of $\tau$ still has variance $\sigma^2$.   After some further work, I get that:

$$ p(\theta') = \frac{\Phi \left( \frac{\tilde\mu(\theta') - t}{\tilde\sigma} \right)}{\Phi \left( \frac{\mu - t}{\sigma} \right)} \phi\left( \frac{ \theta' - \rho\mu }{ \gamma } \right) $$

Where $\gamma^2 = \sigma^2 \rho ^ 2 + \epsilon^2 $, $\tilde\sigma = \sigma \epsilon / \gamma$ and $$\tilde\mu(\theta') = \frac{\mu\epsilon^2 + \rho\sigma^2\theta'}{ \sigma^2\rho^2 + \epsilon^2 } $$

Simulation confirms that this is correct.

So the question is now: why does taking the product of a normal pdf of $\theta'$ (the $\phi(\cdot)$ term) and the cdf of a linear transform of $\theta'$ (the $\Phi(\cdot)$ term) produce a normal?  And what are its parameters?  This seems like it should be a known property, but I couldn't find a reference anywhere.  Suggestions very welcome!  :)

Comment: UPDATE: It turns out that this isn't exactly normal.  It is close in many circumstances.  But in general, it is not.  Quite what those circumstances are is something that I haven't yet totally worked out.  But some, at least, are obvious.  Like when $\epsilon$ is large relative to $\sigma$.  Or $\rho$ is small.